# Laravel 4.2 Custom Relationship Adding Eager Constraint for Complex Multi DB Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

We are working with a system that links teachers with classes, departments, schools and periodic surveys, responses & answers.

We use limesurvey for the survey component. However the teacher interface is contained within a laravel codebase.

In this example there is a relationship between courses and their surveys. This should be able to return a collection of any survey that is related to that survey.

Here is what I've done in the CourseModel:

```
public function surveys()
{
    $related = new Survey();
    $parent = $this;
    return new CourseSurveysRelation($related->newQuery(), $this);
}
```

The relationship class:

use Pivotal\Cycle\Models\Cycle;
use Pivotal\Models\CourseInterface;
use Pivotal\Survey\Models\Survey;
use Pivotal\Course\Models\Course;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

```
class CourseSurveysRelation extends Relation
{

    /**
     * Create a new relation instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $parent
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Builder $query, CourseInterface $parent)
    {

        $survey_ids = $parent::getModel()
            ->newQuery()
            ->select('cycles_classes.limesurvey_id')
            ->join('cycles_classes', 'classes.id', '=', 'cycles_classes.class_id')
            ->where('cycles_classes.class_id','=',$parent->id)
            ->lists('limesurvey_id');

        $this->query = $query
            ->whereIn('sid', $survey_ids)
            ->groupBy('sid');

        $this->parent = $parent;
        $this->related = $query->getModel();
        $this->addConstraints();
    }


    public function addEagerConstraints(array $models)
    {
        $survey_ids = [];

        $course_ids = $this->getKeys($models, 'id');
        $survey_ids = \DB::table('cycles_classes')
                        ->select('cycles_classes.limesurvey_id')
                        ->whereIn('cycles_classes.class_id',$course_ids)
                        ->lists('limesurvey_id');

        $this->query->whereIn('sid', $survey_ids);
    }

    public function initRelation(array $models, $relation)
    {

    }

    public function addConstraints()
    {

    }

    public function match(array $models, Collection $results, $relation)
    {

    }

    public function getResults()
    {
        $results = $this->query->get();
        return $results;
    }

}
```

To explain the above a bit, the cycles_classes table holds the cycle, class and survey id.

Here is the Survey Model:

```
use \Config;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Pivotal\Course\Models\Course;
use Pivotal\Cycle\Models\Cycle;
use Pivotal\Survey\Models\Collections\SurveyCollection;
use Pivotal\Survey\Models\Relations\SurveyCourseRelation;
use Pivotal\Survey\Models\Relations\SurveyCycleRelation;
use Pivotal\Survey\Models\Relations\SurveyResponseRelation;
use Pivotal\Survey\Models\SurveyInterface;

class Survey extends Model implements SurveyInterface
{
    protected $connection = 'limemysql';
    protected $table = 'surveys';
    protected $primaryKey = 'sid';

public function __construct($attributes = array())
{
    $this->table = Config::get('limesurvey.db_prefix').$this->table;
    parent::__construct($attributes);
}


public function questions()
{
    return $this->HasMany('Pivotal\Survey\Models\Question','sid','sid');
}

public function responses()
{
    $instance = new Response;
    $instance->setSid($this->sid);
    return new SurveyResponseRelation($instance->newQuery(),$this);
}

public function cycle()
{
    $instance = new Cycle();
    return new SurveyCycleRelation($instance->newQuery(),$this);
}

public function course()
{
    $instance = new Course();
    return new SurveyCourseRelation($instance->newQuery(),$this);
}

public function newCollection(array $models = [])
{
    return new SurveyCollection($models);
}

}
```

The code seems right and works when I'm not doing any more complex modifications to the model calls, however for example, when I call:
$parent->with('courses.surveys')->get()
I get the following sql related error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') and `sid` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `surveys` where `sid` in () and `sid` in (531557, 211231, 316692, 899214, 974717, 247825, 697782, 552663, 345392, 818373, 628794, 934974, 181774, 981825, 768386, 556866, 867981, 454781, 997136, 681294, 219854, 536314, 533283, 661282, 419684, 643469, 893499, 951161, 766562, 238263, 289637, 975286, 149335, 179627, 932135, 763659, 219722, 214899, 144844, 381495, 462774, 949323, 918832, 414629, 646126, 342421, 365583, 286479, 386494, 177941, 693328, 634294, 434532, 721241, 881355, 425659, 971835, 997579, 653716, 775787, 437953, 758524, 931996, 557856, 179298, 251354, 236281, 565872, 898672, 862168, 264461, 383562, 855941, 351452, 734981, 523667, 616126, 723435, 282423, 275988, 549494, 644412, 112726, 876769, 637444, 233532, 276116, 953935, 353756, 912427, 862134, 996477, 331321, 322652, 917295, 842584, 123751, 628385, 871618, 417254, 352626, 523421, 217281, 532171, ) group by `sid`)

It seems like I need to get rid of the first instance of $this->query->whereIn('sid', $survey_ids);

What am I missing here?